# Using a conditional maxLength in input filter in Android

Tags: android

I am using input filter:

```
int max_length;
max_length = 15;
InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(max_length);

final EditText input = new EditText(getBaseContext());
input.setFilters(FilterArray);
alert_screen.setView(input);
```

It works, but I need to make max_length a conditional value. For example, if user inputs only digits, max_length will be equal to 15, but if user inputs some letter, max_length must be equal to 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use first `TextWatcher` ,Due to text change in your edittext ....

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html

if user enter any letter in edittext condition of max is changed and if only digits also changed condition and put this condition in `onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)`.

Just refrences is  ::

http://thiranjith.wordpress.com/2010/12/12/how-to-specify-maximum-length-for-edittext-in-android/